# does there exist a generalization of manifold

Tags: geometry, reference-request, manifolds

is there a generalization of a manifold, where instead of being locally like $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is locally some other space?

Comment: Yes: Banach manifolds.

Comment: Following up on @404 Serge Lang's book [**Fundamentals of Differential Geometry**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/038798593X) is a good place to begin looking at [Banach manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_manifold).

Comment: You could maybe have a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Generalized_manifolds